# Swift 3 | Unable to hide status bar on a ViewController

Tags: iphone, swift3, ios10, statusbar

I want to show the status bar on portrait mode only, when I rotate the screen the status bar hides as intended but if I push / show a new View Controller the status bar appears again.

I've tried the following without success:

- Setting `View controller-based status bar appearance` to `NO` in the `info.plist` file
- Using `setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()` on `self` and on `NavigationController`
- Setting `prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool` to `true`
- Also tried `UIApplication.shared.setStatusBarHidden(true, with: UIStatusBarAnimation.none)`
- Also extending NavigationController. [seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33871020/cant-hide-status-bar-in-avplayerviewcontrollers-portrait-mode)

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hide status bar of a single view controller in iOS 9?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35028262/how-to-hide-status-bar-of-a-single-view-controller-in-ios-9)

Comment: Nope, they suggest the same things that i've tried and aren't working for me. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

**Try Following Code**

```
override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {

    if UIDevice.current.orientation.isPortrait{
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: Could you explain a little how this solves the question in addition to the code? Thanks

Comment: I have written this code in main viewController
Also set View controller-based status bar appearance to NO in the info.plist 
When i back to my main viewController after navigation its work fine according to landscape and portrait mode

Comment: Hi @JalpaJani , this is what I'm doing but I did shorten my question with just  'prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool to true' for reading purposes, but thanks anyway!