# How can I stop a status bar animation? - Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift

I want to go from a landscape screen to a portrait screen without a transition animation. The code is working fine, the problem is that the status bar has an animation that I want to get rid of. Any ideas? See the image attached. [image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42833923/1244403 - may help you!

Comment: it didn't work Harish.